# How to patch function's __code__?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I am exploring `__code__` attribute and the `ast` module and found strange behaviour, first call of the function doesn't output anything:

```
In [3]: def foo():
   ...:     print('foo')
   ...:
In [4]: p = ast.parse("".join(inspect.getsourcelines(foo)[0]))
In [5]: p.body[0].body = ast.parse("print('bar')").body
In [6]: foo.__code__ = compile(p, foo.__code__.co_filename, 'exec')
In [7]: foo()  # Nothing happens??

In [8]: foo()  # Okay, let's try again
bar
```

What is happening here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might think you've set `foo.__code__` to a code object that prints `bar`, but that's not what you've done. You've set `foo.__code__` to a code object that *defines a new `foo` function* that prints `bar`. It's kind of like

```
def foo():
    global foo
    def foo():
        print('bar')
```

After the first run, `foo` is the new bar-printing function, and running the new function prints `bar`.

Comment: Thank you! So, the correct way would be to change line 6 to `foo.__code__ = compile(ast.Module(p.body[0].body), foo.__code__.co_filename, 'exec')`.

Comment: @ElectricHedgehog: Maybe? I haven't tried that, and I don't know if you might be traversing the AST wrong or running into some weird edge case or incompatibility.